# Changing multiple characters in a string

Tags: java, loops

So i have a program where i want to replace specific characters in the program with other letters. However, when i run this program, it seems to keep reverting the changed characters back. This is the code so far:

```
  public static String changeSample(String sample) {

    for (int i = 0; i < sample.length(); i++) {

        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'A') {

            sample = sample.replace(sample.charAt(i), 'B');
            continue;

        }

        else if (sample.charAt(i) == 'B') {

            sample = sample.replace(sample.charAt(i), 'A');
            continue;

        }

    }

   return sample;
```

Is there a way that i can iterate through each character in the string and then check if it is either an A, B, C, D, E, or F and change it to its complimentary letter, i.e. A to B, B to A, C to D, D to C, E to F, F to E.

Comment: That's only part of your method. Please show us the rest, as I suspect the issue is a simple misunderstanding about how objects and references work.

Comment: Is your code being compiled ?? you missed `i++` or `i=i+1` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: He didn't miss it, it's inside the `if` statements. However, he'll have an endless loop if the character isn't handled.

Comment: Are you returning a new String with the altered content?  I don't see a return statement.  In the current form, the method won't compile, since it needs to return a String.

Comment: Its the problem of `replace` method that it will replace all occurrences of character in the string.

Comment: @SacJn so would there be another method i should be using instead?

Comment: you just want to change character at one index in that particular iteration and then move on. So @kv.333 seems just best for you.

Answer (score 4):

`replace()` will return a new `String` where ALL occurrences of a particular character are changed, not just a character at a particular position. So your problem is that the repeated `replace()` statements are effectively modifying the values back and forth.

Because a `String` is immutable, you cannot simply replace its characters with others dynamically. So, convert your code to use a `StringBuilder` instead.

```
StringBuilder buildSample = new StringBuilder();
buildSample.append(sample);
```

Now you can use `setCharAt()` instead of `replace()` to change the character at one position at a time.

```
buildSample.setCharAt(i, 'A');
```

At the end, you can return `buildSample.toString()`.

As for changing each letter A to F to its complement, if only these six letters are required, a hard-coded function with a `switch` statement would do. Otherwise you can use a function like `complementaryLetter()` below, which returns the complement after checking the ASCII value of the character. This will work for all characters. You can add code to handle invalid cases, for non-character input.

**A complete working code:**

```
public class Replace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "ABCDEFA";
        System.out.println(s1);
        s1 = changeSample(s1);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

    public static char complementaryLetter(char letter) {
        char retChar = 'A';
        if ((int) letter % 2 == 0)
            retChar = (char) ((int)letter - 1);
        else
            retChar = (char) ((int) letter + 1);
        return retChar;
    }

    public static String changeSample(String sample) {
        StringBuilder buildSample = new StringBuilder();
        buildSample.append(sample);
        for (int i = 0; i < sample.length(); i++) {
            buildSample.setCharAt(i, complementaryLetter(sample.charAt(i)));
        }
        return buildSample.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Though your answer is correct but I doubt correctness of your explanation. You said that **Because a String is immutable, you cannot simply replace one character at a time** , can you please explain a little more ? As I know, String being immutable can't be modified and it doesn't really care about if a single character is modified or multiple.

Comment: Yes, a String cannot be modified at all. I was giving a more specific response to his requirement of changing characters, saying it cannot be done like that.

Comment: I edited my answer to remove that ambiguity, thanks.